# Jackpot game is not returning result text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Background Info:

Jackpot Game created and at the end of each round - will show a text of either a win or a lose

What has been done:

created a switch statement to check the element of each slot. Created a conditional check statement to check if all 3 slots are identical - will be a win, else it will be a lost

Issue:

at the end of each spin- There is no update text of either a win or a lost:

CODE:

```
var BLURB_TBL = [
'JACKPOT!'
];
switch (this.state) {
case 1: // all slots spinning
if (now - this.lastUpdate > RUNTIME) {
    this.state = 2;
    this.lastUpdate = now;
}
break;
case 2: // slot 1
this.stopped1 = _check_slot( this.offset1, this.result1 );
if ( this.stopped1 ) {
    this.speed1 = 0;
    this.state++;
    this.lastUpdate = now;
}
break;
case 3: // slot 1 stopped, slot 2
this.stopped2 = _check_slot( this.offset2, this.result2 );
if ( this.stopped2 ) {
    this.speed2 = 0;
    this.state++;
    this.lastUpdate = now;
}
break;
case 4: // slot 2 stopped, slot 3
this.stopped3 = _check_slot( this.offset3, this.result3 );
if ( this.stopped3 ) {
    this.speed3 = 0;
    this.state++;
}
break;
case 5: // slots stopped 
if ( now - this.lastUpdate > 3000 ) {
    this.state = 6;
}
break;
case 6: // check results

if ((that.items1[that.result1].id == 'gold-64' && that.items2[that.result2].id == 'gold-64' && that.items3[that.result3].id == 'gold-64') || (that.items1[that.result1].id == 'cash-64' && that.items2[that.result2].id == 'cash-64' && that.items3[that.result3].id == 'cash-64') || (that.items1[that.result1].id == 'energy-64' && that.items2[that.result2].id == 'energy-64' && that.items3[that.result3].id == 'energy-64') || (that.items1[that.result1].id == 'staff-64' && that.items2[that.result2].id == 'staff-64' && that.items3[that.result3].id == 'staff-64') || (that.items1[that.result1].id == 'build-64' && that.items2[that.result2].id == 'build-64' && that.items3[that.result3].id == 'build-64') || (that.items1[that.result1].id == 'goods-64' && that.items2[that.result2].id == 'goods-64' && that.items3[that.result3].id == 'goods-64')){
    $('#status').text(BLURB_TBL);
}else {
    $('#status').text("GOOD TRY!!");
}




this.state = 7;
break;
case 7: // game ends
break;
default:
}
this.lastupdate = now;
```

Comment: `not returning...` there is no function, therefore nothing can return

Comment: @JaromandaX this is within a function

Comment: @Luke if it is within function then you are missing return statement

Comment: @Justcode arh....thks!

Comment: ok, there's no return statement, so nothing is returned

Comment: @Luke. What is `that` here. How is this function getting called. Who is updating the `state`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return function.

For this example:

```
function a() {
    alert('A');
}
//alerts 'A', returns undefined

function b() {
    alert('B');
    return a;
}
//alerts 'B', returns function a

function c() {
    alert('C');
    return a();
}
//alerts 'C', alerts 'A', returns undefined

alert("Function 'a' returns " + a());
alert("Function 'b' returns " + b());
alert("Function 'c' returns " + c());
```